# json curl GET request Drupal 7

Tags: php, json, curl, drupal-7

I am trying to retrieve json data from an external url using the curl method in drupal 7. 
So i have my function that retrieves the data:

```
////jSON URL which should be requested
$gry_str = "?timezone=".urlencode(date_default_timezone_get())
            ."&dateFrom=".date('Y-m-d')."&dateTill=".date('Y-m-d');

$json_url = 'http://www.example.com/json/financial-calendar.json'.$gry_str;
// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init(); 

//Configuring curl options 
$options=array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
                CURLOPT_URL => $json_url);

//Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

//Getting resutls
$results = curl_exec($ch); //Getting json result string
curl_close($ch);
```

When i tried loading or refreshing the page firebug display the headers and the parameters but not the response and the html. 
It also displays status 200 Ok.

When i tried echoing the url and test it on the web browser it displays the array of data correctly. I am trying to display the retrieved data to an html table with no success.

I have no idea where is the error or even if i am doing this the right way in drupal. 
Please help..i am lost.

Comment: What happens when you execute this code echo file_get_contents($json_url); instead using curl?

Comment: Its the same! It prints the contents of the external url in my homepage at the very top. And still the response in Firebug is empty.  Am i doing something wrong?? Is drupal uses something different than that i did? I have no idea where the error is!

Comment: Please note that i am using WAMP server on localhost.

Comment: Are you using Ajax to call a Drupal menu path and then calling the external URL to get JSON and returning the response back to the front-end?

Comment: I dont think the path is the problem since the results of the json file are printed at the top of the page when i echo the external url. Anyhow the json files are located on the host that i am going to host my website after development is done.  What do you mean when you say am i using Ajax to call a menu path and then calling the external URL to get the JSON file? I have read also about creating a module that will use the hook_menu to retrieve the JSON using curl. Are you referring to this?

Comment: Well I was just trying to understand your question better, if you are not making a Ajax call then you won't see any response in Firebug's response tab. I think the problem is that you are not returning the response back the way it is supposed to be returned. If you can post some of your code logic like how you are calling the menu path and function that handles the request etc., it will be help in answering your question quickly.